# What is the point of a Semigroup for Int in cats?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In the cats docs they show an example for Semigroup[Int]:

```scala
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val rightwards = List(1, 2, 3).foldRight(0)(_ |+| _)
```

So the `|+|` operator is a semigroup combine.  What's the point of this extra machinery if good 'ol "+" works just fine here?  What does the Semigroup buy you for Int, or likely for any simple type for that matter?

Comment: `Semigroup` is an abstraction, `Int` `+` is an implementation. Abstractions (FP type classes or OOP interfaces/traits) are good for [decoupling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269806/dependency-inversion-decoupling).

Comment: The point of an abstraction is usually using it on an abstract context, is like asking what is the point of `Animal` if I all I want is a `Dog` - BTW, in this case you can actually see advantages without needing to go abstract, just use `combineAll` rather than `foldRight` or use `|+|` with two maps whose values are `Ints`

Comment: In addition to the above comments, basically these are all building blocks of a bigger building, so your question can be expanded to: "What's the point of a Semigroup, Monoid, and so on?", and the answer would be clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103426/why-is-functor-in-scala-cats-required

Comment: I like the point with Animal and Dog and to fine grain + is the "operation" on them which could be "kill" or "love" each other. Cats provides the implementation for primitive data types. If have a case class let's say case class SalesCustomer( count:Int, value:Int) you can then create a semigroup to add up the number of all sales and revenue without having to implement the operation of Semigroup(Int,+) in first place.

Answer (score 0):

`Semigroup` is an abstraction. The point of it is that you can abstract things.

Instead of

```scala
def combineIntList(xs: List[Int]) = xs.foldRight(0)(_ + _)
def combineDoubleList(xs: List[Double]) = xs.foldRight(0d)(_ + _)
def combineStringList(xs: List[String]) = xs.foldRight("")(_ + _)
```

You write

```scala
def combine[A: Monoid](xs: List[A]) = xs.foldRight(Monoid[A].empty)(_ |+| _)
```

The free (pay what you want) ebook [Scala with Cats](https://www.scalawithcats.com/dist/scala-with-cats.html) talks about these concepts in much more detail